# Samba share to windows permission specific

Tags: windows, samba

I've a Centos server with a Samba 3.6. The Samba Config are written below：

```
[global]
log level =2
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
hide dot files = no
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY
security = share
passdb backend = tdbsam


[AsgardServer]
path = /local/asgard/asgard_server
public = yes
writable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
hide dot files = no
```

Then I mount it to the windows as R：/ and it seems fine.But the security properties of the file under R:/ are Specific, not full control. All those files on the server are 0777 and the owner are the root.Then I cannot modify those files on windows. So whats wrong?

Comment: When changing permission in windows and return failed,I can see such period in samba log:[2013/06/28 16:11:18.465525,  2] smbd/posix_acls.c:2850(set_canon_ace_list)
  set_canon_ace_list: sys_acl_set_file type file failed for file Platform1000/workspace/tc/asgard/basic/AsgardSleep.tc (Operation not supported).

Answer (score 0):

On of the solutions to set owners would be to add  for each share read/write list. You can specify users

```
    read list = bob123 anna456
    write list = bob123 anna456
```

or use groups that are defined in /etc/groups

```
    read list = @dwarfs
    write list = @wizards
```

To set file/dir mode (in sense of  chmod) you can play with parameters below:

```
    force create mode = 0666
    force directory mode = 6775
```

or

```
    create mask = 644
    directory mask = 755
```

The directories with data have to have unix permission allowing bob123 anna456 to read and write in them. If directory /local/asgard/asgard_server is owned by root and it has flag 755 neither Bob nor Anna can write in this directory using samba share.

Comment: But under /local/asgard/asgard_server there are many files whose bitmask is 777 and the owner is root. And those files can not be modified.